# Git Bash - all commits since last merge

Tags: bash, git

Is there any way to automate the merge commit message to be automatically populated?

What I need when merging is basically:

1. Find out what are all of the commit messages since last merge.
2. Include all of these messages in my merge.

So for instance, merge happened - and since this merge there are 3 commits:

Commit A - did A stuff
Commit B - did B stuff
Commit C - did C stuff

And I want my merge commit message to display:

"Merged BranchA to BranchB :

Commit A - did A stuff

Commit B - did B stuff

Commit C - did C stuff"

Anybody aware on how to do this in git bash?

***USING VIM***

Comment: What do you mean by "using vim"?

Comment: Well that whenever I go commit anything or merge anything I get into VIM editor menu to actually type in the message. It would be great if I could actually type git merge BranchB and get the required message there in VIM already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a combined log message with something like

```
git log --oneline BranchB..BranchA
```

where you're merging `BranchA` into `BranchB`; this will give the one-line summary of every commit reachable from `BranchA` but *not* reachable from `BranchB` - which is to say, the commits whose changes will be merged into `BranchB`.

So you could get close with

```
git merge -m "$(git log --oneline BranchB..BranchA)" BranchA
```

(assuming this won't result in a fast-forward; you could use `--no-ff` to force the issue if needed).

But this drops the `Merged BranchA into BranchB` part.  So if that's an issue, you could instead write a script merge-msg.sh

```
echo Merged $1 into $2
echo
git log --oneline $2..$1
```

And then use

```
git merge -m "$(merge-msg.sh BranchA BranchB)" BranchA
```

You could use `HEAD` instead of `BranchB`, but then that again will lose information (the current branch name) in the commit message.

And of course you could try using `git alias` to cut down on the repetitive typing.

---

*Update* - So you want an alias?  Well, since I don't use `git alias` much (ever), this may not be the most straight-forward way, but:

1) Create another script myMerge.sh and put it somewhere you can access

```
git checkout $2
git merge -m "$(/path/to/merge-msg.sh $1 $2)" $1
```

2) Create the alias

```
git config --global alias.mymerge !/path/to/mymerge.sh
```

Then

```
git mymerge feature master
```

would merge `feature` into `master`

Answer (score 0):

`git merge` has a `--log` option.

See the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---logltngt).